# How to call ViewControllers in regular sequence at AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, appdelegate

now I am developing messenger

MessengerBox is tableViewController, when user tap the one of the cell, then chatRoomViewcontroller is presented.

if the app is not running and message arrived, then push notifications show. And user Tap the notification, App shows chatRoomViewcontroller directly.

Initially, I implemented this code by using window.rootViewController

But the problem happened. when I tap Back Button of chatRoomviewController, change is not happened because this view controller is rootview and its presentingViewController is empty!

so I fixed it like below

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    ///some code for notification..

        let mVC  //this is MessengerBoxViewcontroller
        let crVC  //this is ChatRoomViewController


        CRVC?.sender = "asdf"
        do{
            self.window?.rootViewController = mVC
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            defer{
                mVC?.presentChatRoomVC()
            }
        }

     /// some code...
}
```

It works! But I'd like to know better way.
And Also I think I should study How window and viewcontrollers works.

please recommend me the better way, and reference documents.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle back button action programatically in `ChatRoomViewController`to solve your problem :

On back button Click :

1. Check for MessengerBoxViewcontroller is present in navigationController stack.
2. if `MessengerBoxViewcontroller` is in navigationController stack then pop to move back to `MessengerBoxViewcontroller`.
3. Else present `MessengerBoxViewcontroller`.

   ```
   if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
        for viewController in viewControllers {

           if viewController.isKindOfClass(MessengerBoxViewcontroller) {
               print("Your controller exist")
               navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

            }
         }
   }
   else {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "messengerBoxViewcontroller") as! MessengerBoxViewcontroller
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

Comment: Did you try this solution ?